Query that can take only number character in varchar?
I have a column GL_DESCRIPTION which has a values like this
SELECT DISTINCT GL_DESCRIPTION 
FROM database_actual_pemupukan;


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3 EMDEK - TRANSPORT
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2 EMDEK - UPAH
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2  - MATERIAL
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1  - TRANSPORT
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3  - MATERIAL
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1  - MATERIAL
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2 EMDEK - MATERIAL
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3 EMDEK - MATERIAL
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1 EMDEK - MATERIAL
PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1 EMDEK - TRANSPORT

I have a new column in INT called Rotasi which can store value any number character after 'ROTASI'
So for that requirement, my code would be like this:
UPDATE database_actual_pemupukan 
SET Rotasi = SUBSTRING(GL_DESCRIPTION, 
                       PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION), 
                       LEN(GL_DESCRIPTION));

It returns an error:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1  - MATERIAL' to data type int

Also I tried this query
UPDATE database_actual_pemupukan
SET rotasi = CASE 
                 WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION) > 0 
                     THEN CAST(
                               -- Extract the number starting from the first digit
                               SUBSTRING(GL_DESCRIPTION, 
                                         PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION), 
                                         CASE 
                                             WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION + 'a') = 0 
                                                 THEN LEN(GL_DESCRIPTION) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION) + 1
                                                 ELSE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION + 'a') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION)
                                         END) AS INT)
                 ELSE NULL -- If no number is found, set rotasi to NULL
             END;

This query returns this error:

Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Where am I wrong at?

I suggest extracting the number outside of SQL Server, before you bring this data into your table.

sorry i've got the data from the sql server itself. i know the data situation is not ideal. but is there any query from sql that can solve this situation?

You started off on the right track, you just need to be methodical in completing your extraction e.g.

Find the first numeric character as you did
Find the first space after the first numeric character
Then substring between them

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3 EMDEK - TRANSPORT'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2 EMDEK - UPAH'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2  - MATERIAL'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1  - TRANSPORT'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3  - MATERIAL'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1  - MATERIAL'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2 EMDEK - MATERIAL'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3 EMDEK - MATERIAL'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1 EMDEK - MATERIAL'),
        ('PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1 EMDEK - TRANSPORT')
    ) x (GL_DESCRIPTION)
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        GL_DESCRIPTION
        , PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION) FirstNumber, LEN(GL_DESCRIPTION) Length
    FROM cte1
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT *
        , CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(GL_DESCRIPTION, FirstNumber, Length-FirstNumber)) FirstSpace
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT
    GL_DESCRIPTION
    , CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(GL_DESCRIPTION, FirstNumber, FirstSpace)) ExtractedNumber
FROM cte3;

Returns:



GL_DESCRIPTION
ExtractedNumber




PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3 EMDEK - TRANSPORT
3


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2 EMDEK - UPAH
2


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2  - MATERIAL
2


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1  - TRANSPORT
1


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3  - MATERIAL
3


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1  - MATERIAL
1


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 2 EMDEK - MATERIAL
2


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 3 EMDEK - MATERIAL
3


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1 EMDEK - MATERIAL
1


PEMUPUKAN - CPD HIK ROTASI 1 EMDEK - TRANSPORT
1



DBFiddle
Note: You can do this as a one liner if desired, I've just shown each calculation separately for clarity (and because I don't like duplicating code).

Thank you very much, after i saw your code, this is my final query SUBSTRING(GL_DESCRIPTION, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION),1);
Thank you once again

You don't need three CTEs to do this, one query would actually be just fine.

@TimBiegeleisen as I said in my answer, I wanted to spell out each of the computations for the OP... of course you can combine them all into a single query (as you've done). For someone who is new to it, it can be hard to pick apart a one liner such as yours - so I leave it to them to combine them once they understand. (I often use cross apply for real, because I hate duplicating the calculations - but again many newbies understand CTEs better than cross apply).

We can use a substring trick here along the lines of what you were trying, with PATINDEX() and REVERSE():
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(
        GL_DESCRIPTION,
        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION),
        LEN(GL_DESCRIPTION) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(GL_DESCRIPTION)) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', GL_DESCRIPTION) + 2) AS GL_DESCRIPTION_INT
    FROM database_actual_pemupukan
)

UPDATE cte
SET rotasi = CONVERT(INT, GL_DESCRIPTION_INT);

The logic above works by finding the two points in the string where the integer starts and ends, then taking a substring.
Here is a demo showing that the logic to extract the integer is working.
